# How to make button a invisible when other buttons are clicked

Tags: c#

I'm creating a new project with Guna Framework UI [image]

I set another button(**btnMove**) behind the first button "Dashboard" that moves to the new button location that gets clicked in that left panel.
I want to make the **btnMove** to be invisible when I click buttons from the right panel.
These are my codes

```
 //moving disabled button across buttons in the same panel when clicked
    private void MoveButton(object sender)
    {
        Guna2Button b = (Guna2Button)sender;
        btnMove.Visible = true;
        btnMove.FillColor = Color.White;
        btnMove.Animated = true;
        btnMove.Location = new Point(b.Location.X + 24, b.Location.Y + 1);
        btnMove.SendToBack();
    }
    //end here       

   private void guna2Button1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Calling the move function 
            MoveButton(sender);
            
        }
```

I tried to set the btnMove to be invisible only when I click on the buttons on the right panel but it doesn't seem to work
[image]

```
 private void guna2Button3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    guna2Button1.Checked = false;
    btnMove.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Invisible (as per the body of the question) or lose focus (as per the title)?

Comment: Invisible per question